# Find Members Not included in SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three datasets, one with members who have come in in March and one with members with have come in during June. The third data set shows which members have come in during March AND June. Out of 19,000, 10,000ish have come in during both months. Now I want a fourth dataset that shows members who came in during March but not June. I'm trying to do this with a subquery in the WHERE clause. But it's returning 0, when it should be returning 9,000ish.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AH.MEMBER_NBR)
FROM ACCOUNTHISTORY AS AH
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT AS MP on AH.MEMBER_NBR=MP.MEMBER_NBR
INNER JOIN INDIVIDUAL AS I ON MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID= I.INDIVIDUAL_ID



INNER JOIN(SELECT AH.MEMBER_NBR AS JuneMember, I.TIN AS JUNETIN
FROM ACCOUNTHISTORY AS AH
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT AS MP on AH.MEMBER_NBR=MP.MEMBER_NBR
INNER JOIN INDIVIDUAL AS I ON MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID= I.INDIVIDUAL_ID
WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '06/01/2020' AND ENTRY_DATE <= '06/17/2020'
AND FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 101 AND 3199
AND TOKEN_STRING NOT LIKE '%PHONE%')June on AH.MEMBER_NBR = June.JuneMember


WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '03/01/2020' AND ENTRY_DATE <= '03/17/2020'
AND FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 101 AND 3199
AND TOKEN_STRING NOT LIKE '%PHONE%'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT AH.MEMBER_NBR AS JuneMember, I.TIN AS JUNETIN
FROM ACCOUNTHISTORY AS AH
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT AS MP on AH.MEMBER_NBR=MP.MEMBER_NBR
INNER JOIN INDIVIDUAL AS I ON MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID= I.INDIVIDUAL_ID
WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '06/01/2020' AND ENTRY_DATE <= '06/17/2020'
AND FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 101 AND 3199
AND TOKEN_STRING NOT LIKE '%PHONE%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AH.MEMBER_NBR)
FROM ACCOUNTHISTORY AS AH
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT AS MP on AH.MEMBER_NBR=MP.MEMBER_NBR
INNER JOIN INDIVIDUAL AS I ON MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID= I.INDIVIDUAL_ID


LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT AH.MEMBER_NBR AS JuneMember, I.TIN AS JUNETIN
FROM ACCOUNTHISTORY AS AH
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT AS MP on AH.MEMBER_NBR=MP.MEMBER_NBR
INNER JOIN INDIVIDUAL AS I ON MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID= I.INDIVIDUAL_ID
WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '06/01/2020' AND ENTRY_DATE <= '06/17/2020'
AND FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 101 AND 3199
AND TOKEN_STRING NOT LIKE '%PHONE%')June ON AH.MEMBER_NBR = June.JuneMember


WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '03/01/2020' AND ENTRY_DATE <= '03/17/2020'
AND FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 101 AND 3199
AND TOKEN_STRING NOT LIKE '%PHONE%'
AND June.JuneMember IS NULL
```